# Filter Sentinel-2 imageCollection with different tiles

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I am working with Google Earth Engine Code Editor. I am trying to load a collection of Sentinel-2 images as shown below:

```
var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry);
```

I get an image collection with images in different tiles (30TYL, 31TBE, 30TYK, 31SBD, 30SYJ). However I want only the images in tiles 30TYL and 30TYK. If I filter a single tile, my code works correctly, as shown here:

```
var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'EQUALS','30TYL');
```

But it does not work when I pass a list of tiles to it:

```
var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'EQUALS', ['30TYL', '30TYK']);
```

Filtering with `ee.Filter.or` does not work either. You only get the images in the 30TYL tile.

```
var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE', '30TYL'), ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE', '30TTYK')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this worked using `ee.Filter.inList`:

```
var tiles = ['30TYL', '30TTYK'];

var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-03-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles));
```